# Web scraping rvest problems basketball players

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm having trouble reading the data from the url https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_totals.html#totals_stats::pts. Here's the code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_totals.html#totals_stats::pts"
pagina <- read_html(url, as.data.frame=T, stringsAsFactors = TRUE, 
                encoding = "utf-8")
pagina %>%  
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
  html_table(fill=T) -> x
```

This reads the table, but I don't know why it paste a few rows like this:

```
    Rk  Player  Pos Age Tm  G   GS  MP  FG  FGA FG% 3P  3PA 3P% 2P  2PA 2P% eFG%    FT  FTA FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS
54  Rk  Player  Pos Age Tm  G   GS  MP  FG  FGA FG% 3P  3PA 3P% 2P  2PA 2P% eFG%    FT  FTA FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS
77  Rk  Player  Pos Age Tm  G   GS  MP  FG  FGA FG% 3P  3PA 3P% 2P  2PA 2P% eFG%    FT  FTA FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS
102 Rk  Player  Pos Age Tm  G   GS  MP  FG  FGA FG% 3P  3PA 3P% 2P  2PA 2P% eFG%    FT  FTA FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS
133 Rk  Player  Pos Age Tm  G   GS  MP  FG  FGA FG% 3P  3PA 3P% 2P  2PA 2P% eFG%    FT  FTA FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS
162 Rk  Player  Pos Age Tm  G   GS  MP  FG  FGA FG% 3P  3PA 3P% 2P  2PA 2P% eFG%    FT  FTA FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS
189 Rk  Player  Pos Age Tm  G   GS  MP  FG  FGA FG% 3P  3PA 3P% 2P  2PA 2P% eFG%    FT  FTA FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS
218 Rk  Player  Pos Age Tm  G   GS  MP  FG  FGA FG% 3P  3PA 3P% 2P  2PA 2P% eFG%    FT  FTA FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS
```

I get the players rows but I also get those rows. I don't know if those rows are also players that aren't being read well or they are just random rows that are pasted because I'm doing something wrong in the code. I want either to remove those rows (which are in random positions as you can see) or modify the read code so I don't get them.

Thanks in advance.

Alberto

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you are facing? You get all the rows from the table you want right? It's just that the order is not correct?

Comment: I get the players rows but I also get those rows, I don't know if those rows are also players that aren't being read well or they are just random rows that are pasted because I'm doing something wrong in the code. I want either to remove those rows (which are in random positions as you can see) or modify the read code so I don't get them. Maybe I haven't explained myself right, my mistake, I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore those rows and take only the relevant rows.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_totals.html"
webpage <- url %>%  read_html 

webpage %>%
   html_table() %>%  
   .[[1]] %>%
   filter(!grepl('Rk', Rk)) %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) 


#   Rk                   Player Pos Age  Tm  G GS   MP  FG  FGA   FG% ...
#1   1             Steven Adams   C  26 OKC 58 58 1564 262  443 0.591 ...
#2   2              Bam Adebayo  PF  22 MIA 65 65 2235 408  719 0.567 ...
#3   3        LaMarcus Aldridge   C  34 SAS 53 53 1754 391  793 0.493 ...
#4   4 Nickeil Alexander-Walker  SG  21 NOP 41  0  501  77  227 0.339 ...
#5   5            Grayson Allen  SG  24 MEM 30  0  498  79  176 0.449 ...
#6   6            Jarrett Allen   C  21 BRK 64 58 1647 267  413 0.646 ...
#7   7             Kadeem Allen  SG  27 NYK 10  0  117  19   44 0.432 ...
#8   8          Al-Farouq Aminu  PF  29 ORL 18  2  380  25   86 0.291 ...
#9   9          Justin Anderson  SF  26 BRK  3  0   17   1    6 0.167 ...
#10 10            Kyle Anderson  PF  26 MEM 59 20 1140 138  280 0.493 ...
#11 11            Ryan Anderson  PF  31 HOU  2  0   14   2    7 0.286 ...
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll do that. But any clue on why I'm getting those?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. It is weird that the table does not show any such entries but while scraping we get those rows.