# Scraping texts from webpage

Tags: r, rvest

I've been trying to scrape texts from [this website](https://www.sephora.com/product/virgin-marula-tm-luxury-facial-oil-P392245?icid2=products%20grid:p392245) but I can't seem to do it correctly.

I've tried searching and trying different ways but I just can't seem to scrape the reviews section as texts at the bottom of the page. Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
newurl <- "https://www.sephora.com/product/virgin-marula-tm-luxury-facial-oil-P392245?icid2=products%20grid:p392245"
newurl <- read_html(newurl)
text <- newurl %>% html_nodes(".css-7rv8g1")
text <- html_text(text)
```

What I did was use a CSS selector to get the nodes for the review section which was .css-7rv8g1 and then I selected that node to get the text with the following code but it returns me an empty string.

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
It would help if you added the necessary libraries to your example code. Also, do you want to scrape the review-text, the stars, or the entire object?

Comment: Also take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667052/3212698

Comment: @mhh hey thanks for the reply, I used rves,xml2 and dplyr for this. I'm looking to scrape the review-text to be exact. Thanks and I will look at that link!